# Reconfigure logback ThresholdFilter level dynamically or based on caller?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm using logback to log `TRACE` to a file and log `DEBUG` to console as well using `ThresholdFilter` in `STDOUT` appender similar to configuration below.

A utility class `FooUtils` does a lot of tracing and normally I just want it in file, not console, but when this class is used by `BarGenerator`'s `main` method I'd like to see the output from `FooUtils` in console by lowering the threshold or otherwise. Is it possible?

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>foo.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a [mapped diagnostic context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) attribute in the BarGenerator's main method. As long as you stay within the same thread, all logged messages will be tagged with this attribute, and you can filter them based on this attribute within the appender.